# HTML: Can't make my PNG image fully transparent. it has the website background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a png image, which has no background, to the website, but it still grabs the grey background colour and adds a weir extra "tail" to the image. Why this happens and how do I prevent it?

[image: This is the image of how it looks]

My code is this...

HTML

```
<body>
<center>
<div id="parte1" class="container">
    <a href="https://tiendaclaro.pe"> <img src="icons/LogoClaro.png" 
        alt="Claro" 
        height="75" 

         >
    
    </a>

</div>


</center>
```

CSS

```
 *{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#parte1{
    background-color: #da291c;


}


#logo{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
```

And even adding a colour background to the .png still has that extra weird grey thing next to it

[image: Changing colour background]

```
#logo{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color:  #da291c;

}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the image?

Comment: You have given absolutely every element a light gray background.What happens when you remove that? There is not enough code in your question for us to be able to find out what that extra element creating a 'tail' is. Please work on making an example which actually shows the problem otherwise any answer is just a guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -2):

```
#parte1 img {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment explaining your solution.